# How to add new column in existing pojo : Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I am working on spring boot and using Postgres DB.
I have a requirement like I need to add a new column in an existing table.

```java
    @Entity
    @TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "EnumUserType", typeClass = EnumUserType.class)})
    public class P_user {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
    "p_user_row_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "p_user_row_id_generator",
            sequenceName = "p_user_row_id_sequence",
            allocationSize = 50)
    @Column(name = "row_id")
    private Long rowId;

    private UUID p_Id;

    private String username;

    @Type(type = "EnumUserType", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "enumClassName", value = "P_userRole")})
    private P_userRole role;

    private Date startTime;

    private Date endTime;

    //new Id tobe added
    private UUID groupId;
    }
```

I am uisng script to dynamically alter the table in db.

in xyz.sql file

```
  ALTER TABLE p_user ADD COLUMN groupId UUID;
```

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
   bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateSqlException: 
    
    Migration xyz.sql failed
    -----------------------------------------------
    SQL State  : 42701
    Error Code : 0
    Message    : ERROR: column "groupid" of relation "p_user" already exists
    Location   : ../db/migration/xyz.sql 
    Line       : 4
    Statement  : ALTER TABLE p_user ADD COLUMN groupId UUID
```

if i don't run this script then i get

```
ERROR: column "group_id" of relation "p_user" does not exist.
```

How can i get new column to existing the entity and i need to alter the table too in db.

Please help me here .Any suggestion is welcome!
TIA!

Comment: Guessing the default behavior converts `groupId` to snake_case, which results in the query as `select ..., group_id ...`.  Try specifying the column name, e.g., @Column(name = "groupId")

Comment: Whilst in development you can just the DDL.update flag to true in your config file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you *can* just script this directly in code. Flyway migrations are covered in the Spring Boot docs at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool.

The general idea is that you enable flyway, put the migration scripts in a common location, and spring initialization and flyway take over from there. "Enable flyway", in our case, was just add the dependency to pom.xml (I *think* that achieves what the docs describe as "add the org.flywaydb:flyway-core to your classpath") and we put a property `spring.flyway.enabled=true` in application.properties.

Your filename alone looks rather fishy; xyz.sql. Flyway migrations usually have the form `V<VERSION>__<NAME>.sql`. Note that those are 2 '_' in a row separating the "Version string" from the "Name string".

Flyway wants that name to be "Version" and if you do it with static sql in a db.migrations directory, the names look like...

`Vabc__some_friendly_text.sql`

Flyway is using the stuff to the right of that initial "V" to "version" the migrations. So "xyz" isn't a great place to start as there isn't much room for new migrations (xyz, xzz, yyz, yzz, zyz, zzz, uh oh...). Usually you see people using something like ISO-8601 strings there.

```
V20210101__create.sql
V20210102__add_foo_table.sql
V20210201__index_something_add_some_data.sql
```

I don't know if this is remotely what you asked...but this is how we leverage Flyway in Spring Boot to get our Database Schema under version control. The Spring Docs are a great place to start. The baeldung folks do a good summary too: https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway

Comment: Although, you _can_ write your Migrations in Java, but the Vxxxxx__something.sql still applies at the Vxxxxxx level.